# How to set up a multi screen setup with NVIDIA and Intel I915 on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a desktop with an integrated I915 iGPU and a monitor attached to it. I recently bought a NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] card with and a new monitor. On the desktop I have a Debian + Gnome setup.

I will like to setup a multi screen setup, having my desktop appearing in both screens.

With the free NVIDIA driver, it's possible to have the desired setup. Some glitches but manageable. But I want to have the proprietary NVIDIA driver for games compatibility ;).

When I install the proprietary NVIDIA driver the I915 monitor disappears and is not reachable any more.

I have been googleing around and I have found some references to NIVIDIA PRIME as a solution for that. But my expertise on graphical is not so good and I'm having problems to fully understand the concepts.

Has anyone manage to build a configuration like that? Any pointer on how to do it? A basic explanation of the concepts involved? Anything will be of help.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you plug both monitors into the 1030? You may need an adaptor to do this but I would suggest you run everything off the external card and forget about the integrated one.

Comment: Not without an adaptor. Yes, I agree that will probably solve the issue, because the second monitor connector is detected by xrandr, but still will be nice to do it by configuration. At the end, one day I can get a third monitor :)